# How to make api for sorting and filter store in php

Tags: php, mysqli

How to make the api for sorting and filtering store in php

User can sorting and Filtering  store   following ways
Sort by :

1. sort by distance
2. sort by Rating
3. Popularity

Filter by :

1. bookmark
2. Open now
3. Rated 3.0 +

More Filter:

1. Wifi
2. parking
3. out door seating
4. order online

Suppose user select distance option from sorted by it show  only those store they located near with user

suppose user select distance option and bookmark option they show only those store they located near with user and bookmark by user so on. And user can also more filter.

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of API you want to make? RESTful? or just JSON / XML request-response style?

Comment: I want to  just show store data in json format